# Log4j2 prints on Console works find, but no log file created

Tags: java, spring, jersey, log4j2

I am using Spring + Jersey, but no Spring Boot. When I set up Log4j2, messages are printed on console, but no log file created.

The configuration XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="FILE" fileName="logfile.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.karapax" level="error"/>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

It a Maven project, and in my pom.xml, the related Library are shown below. I didn't give all the other libraries being used in this project.

```xml
<!-- Spring dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Log Dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I Run the code below on local Tomcat.

```
@Path("log/")
public class LogTestServelt extends BaseServlet {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    public void testLog() {
        logger.debug("This is a debug message");
        logger.info("This is an info message");
        logger.warn("This is a warn message");
        logger.error("This is an error message");
    }
}
```

When I am trying to send a request to this endpoint, the messages print out on console is OK, but no log file is created.

Any one can me? Thanks

Comment: Where do you expect the log file to be created? Why?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In the log4j2 configuration file, I let the error messages print out into console as well as a log file. I didn't specify any file path (only set up the file name), if I am not wrong, the log file should be created at root of this project. This is just a simple example, in the real project, I want to print different level of information into different log files.

Comment: Not the root of the project, no. It'll be created in the current working directory of the Tomcat process. You can find it using the solutions described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But there is no file with the name 'logfile.log' (the log file name I specified) in my computer at all.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The file is created just fine in the current working directory for me, with your config.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis You are right, I give it an absolute path and the file created. Don't why I cannot find it when I am trying to search. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The pathname `"logfile.log"` in your config file is a *relative pathname*.

Since you have specified a relative pathname for the logfile, the file will be created *relative to* the working directory of the running Tomcat process.  The working directory location will depend on precisely how Tomcat was launched.

(We cannot say for certain where the logfile will be.  It might be in your IDE's workspace.  It might be in the Tomcat installation tree.  It could be somewhere else.  It is even possible that Tomcat's working directory is not writeable by the Tomcat process ... and the log file cannot be created.)

Solutions:

- Use an OS specific tool to search for the logfile.  For example, `find` on Linux.
- Specify an absolute pathname for the logfile in the log4j2 config file.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered with the same issue.

Actually, my file was being created ever time, but I was not able to find it.

As per your given configuration, it will be created where you IDE (i.e., Eclipse / STS / Netbeans etc..) is installed. Try to find in that directory. I am sure that you will be able to find it there.

Answer (score -1):

you will find in the tomcat webapp directory